# Error with initial use of JUnit in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, installation, junit

I am attempting to use Junit in an Android Studio project, and I am getting a "No Junit.jar" error.  Can someone point me in the needed documentation to resolve this?  Additionally, any links or step by step instructions for both setup and test case generation (with examples) would be welcome. The "No Junit.jar" occurred when launching the application in the debugger.